# Как понять строку кода (sum(input_data[i-window:i]) / window)?

Tags: python

Как понять строку кода `(sum(input_data[i-window:i]) / window)`?

Неясно это `[i-window:i]`

```py
def moving_average(input_data, window):
    result = []

    for i in range(1, len(input_data)+1):
        if i < window:
            result.append(0)
        else:
            result.append(sum(input_data[i-window:i]) / window)
    return result
```

Comment: Если задача реальная, в списке чисел много, и значение windows не маленькое, то можно сделать в `windows` раз быстрее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ничто иное как срез.

```
input_data[i-window:i]
```

Следущий код: вычисляет сумму элементов, полученных в результате среза `input_data[i-window:i]`

```
sum(input_data[i-window:i])
```

[Документация](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html)

В двух словах, срезы позволяют получить нужную часть из list - предварительно указав границы. **list[START:STOP:STEP]**